# batch command to execute Visual Studio starts as cmd instead of launching

Tags: batch-file

a very simple batch file

```
@echo off
START "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

I'm trying to use a batch file to launch visual studio, where normally I double click on this executable. When run this batch it instead launches visual studio's command line instead of the actual application.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `start /?`.  You'll note the command looks like this: `start ["title"] ... [command/program]`.

Unfortunately this means that just a quoted string gets interpreted as a title and not as a command.

If you insert a dummy title it should be ok.

Comment: Ah yes, this solved it. I should have check the help. I had a strange feeling it had to do with something on visual studio's side, glad I was wrong.